# Autohotkey : bind fast double pression on a key by a combination CTRL + Key

Tags: key, double, bind, autohotkey

That's for a game. I would like when I press fastly 2 times a key, <kbd>A</kbd> for example, to simulate <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>. I'd like to be able to parameter the time in ms of the interval between key pression.

How can I do that please ?

Answer (score 1):

```
a::DoubleTap("^a",250)

DoubleTap(key,TimeVar=300) 
{
        If (A_ThisHotkey==A_PriorHotkey && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < TimeVar)
                Send %key%
        else
                Send {%A_ThisHotkey%}
        return
}
```